# Export postgres table data to shape file to build OSRM cluster

Tags: postgresql, qgis, osrm

I have imported all shapefiles (all 50 states data of USA) to the Postgres/PostGIS DB using QGIS. I am trying to export that data to a single shapefile. I am getting the error below -

```
Failed to write a shape object. File size cannot reach 4294967068 + 248.Error writing shape 31754843
```

How to generate single shapefile of large size as OSRM only takes single .osrm file to deploy in cluster.

I have also tried to merge individual shapefile to single one but it is also not working for me.

Comment: What OS is your PostgreSQL installation running on?

Comment: Postgres is running on macOS Catalina